# Einstein notation for numpy dot product

Tags: numpy, numpy-einsum

How can I write the following dot product using einstein notation?

```
import numpy as np
LHS = np.ones((5,20,2))
RHS = np.ones((20,2))
np.sum([
    np.dot(LHS[:,:,0], RHS[:,0]),
    np.dot(LHS[:,:,1], RHS[:,1]),
], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be -

```
np.einsum('ijk,jk->i',LHS,RHS)
```

Alternatively with `tensordot` -

```
np.tensordot(LHS,RHS,axes=((1,2),(0,1)))
```

And with `np.dot` -

```
LHS.reshape(LHS.shape[0],-1).dot(RHS.ravel())
```